# How does `*((*arr+(i*3))+j)` work when printing a 2D array `arr`?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", *((*arr+(i*3))+j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm surprised how the above code gives the output:

```
1 2 3   
4 5 6
```

I know that `*(arr+i) == arr[i]` and also that I should be using `arr[i][j]` instead of making everything more complicated, but I don't understand how `*((*arr+(i*3))+j)` works.

In my understanding, `*((*arr+(i*3))+j)` can be simplified to `*((*arr)+(i*3)+j)` since the `*`(indirection operator) has the most precedence here.

So, when `i` is zero and `j` iterates through, 0 to 2, the expression is the same as `arr[0][j]` which prints the integers of the first subarray.

My confusion builds up when `i` becomes 1. The next three expressions will be `*((*arr)+(1*3)+0)`, `*((*arr)+(1*3)+1)` and `*((*arr)+(1*3)+2)` which can be simplified to `arr[0][3]`, `arr[0][4]` and `arr[0][5]`.

How does this print the last three values?

Comment: Arrays values are stored contigously.

Comment: Does that mean that `arr[0][3] == arr[1][0]`, `arr[0][4] == arr[1][1]` and `arr[0][5] == arr[1][2]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int arr[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

In memory :

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6
each number on an adjacent memory "cell" the size of an int, in this order
```

Second line :
    i = 1
    j = 0

```
*((*arr+(i*3))+j)) means *((*arr + 3) + 0)-> *({1, 2, 3} + 3) -> *({4, 5, 6}) = 4
```

Keep in mind that `x[n]` is equivalent to `*(x + n)`, whatever `x` or `n`. (This also means `arr[1]` is equivalent to `*(arr + 1)`, `*(1 + arr)` and so `1[arr]` which I find funny)

Here `arr[1][0]` : `x` is `arr[1]` and `n` is `0` so first equivalence: `*(arr[1] + 0)`
Second `x` is `arr` and `n` is `1` so `*(*(arr + 1) + 0)`.
Finally `arr + 1` means the adress at `arr + sizeof(*arr)`, which means:
`(arr + 1)` is equivalent to `(*arr + 3)` because `*arr` is `arr[0]` which is of type `int[3]`

Comment: Nice answer. I'm still confused("_`arr + 1` means `arr` plus the size of one `arr` which is equivalent to `*((*arr + 3) + 0))`_"), though. I guess I need to take a nap to understand. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Yes sorry that bit is unclear. If you have a `char *s` for example, when you do `s = s + 1` the pointer advances one `char` forward. If you have `int *p` and you do `p = p + 1` the pointer advances one *int* forward, which is not the same ^^

Answer (score 3):

The C language stores multidimensional arrays in what is called row-major order,
so when you declare `int arr[2][3]` the memory is actually laid out with the entries of the array occurring adjacent to each other in
memory in this sequence:

```
arr[0][0] arr[0][1] arr[0][2] arr[1][0] arr[1][1] arr[1][2]
```

This has a couple of consequences that are useful to know:

- `arr[1]` acts like a pointer to a one-dimensional array. just as it does when you declare `int **arr;`.
- The initializers in your initialization list are copied into memory locations in exactly the order you list them.

Answer (score 0):

The array is stored in your memory like :

```
_____ _____  _____  _____  _____  _____  
| 1 | | 2 |  | 3 |  | 4 |  | 5 |  | 6 |
----- -----  -----  -----  -----  -----
```

So even though it is stored in a two dimensional array it is contagiously allocated memory during compilation. When you write a[1][1] the compiler accesses the (1*(no of columns) + 1 )  position from front i.e. the 4 position from start.

See http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/23two-dim-array-memory-layout.html